# Extending a sequence to a smooth function

Tags: functions, smooth-functions

Let $a_{n}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a sequence of real numbers. It is easy to see that $a_{n}$ can be extended to a continuous function $a(x):\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (by connecting the dots on the graph of $a_{n}$ with line seqments) but $a(x)$ is not smooth.

Is there a way to extend the sequence $a_{n}$ to a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (I can imagine that this is true)? If yes, is there a way to construct it?

Comment: Just use a bump function with sufficiently small support, and patch.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways of accomplishing this. The functions can differ wildly in value between the support points. It also matters what exactly you mean by smooth. If you only need $C^1$, then the most common means of accomplishing it is cubic splines.

Comment: @PaulSinclair:  Yes, i can imagine that. Maybe I need to restrict the question and be more specific. Is there a construction (involving for example Fourier series or Taylor series) that gives us this extension? Of course we can make a lot of extensions as you mentioned, but all these functions will have really "bad" definitions (mostly used for answering  existence questions). I am interested in way to construct such a function with a more rigid expression (this is way I put in the game Fourier or Taylor series);

Comment: So by smooth, you want "analytic". That is a different story. Analytic interpolation is much more restrictive, indeed nearly unique. I don't have time to look up the relevant information right now, but will try to do so later.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I was thinking of was Weierstrass' theorem that an entire function exists whose zeros are a given sequence diverging to \infty. The application of that theorem is that I was mistaken about "near uniqueness" for analytic interpolations. If $g$ is any entire function, then multiplying $e^g$ by an entire function whose zeros are the positive integers, gives another such function, so they are plentiful. And adding such a function to a solution of your problem produces another such solution. Therefore even for analytic functions there are an infinitude of solutions.

Comment: You can probably generalize Lagrange polynomials to find an analytic interpolation - though you will need to use a technique similar to the one Weierstrass used in the zeros theorem to make the infinite product converge. I haven't sorted out the details. Certainly someone must have done this before, but I didn't turn up a reference.